# node chaincode instantiate behind proxy

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I'm following the official document: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html

I am building my first network. But when I instantiate the node version chaincode, because my machine is working behind the proxy, NPM always throws network exception to me.

I have tried setting proxy in the package.json or scripts, but it does not work.

How can I avoid this?

For example, if I execute:

```
./byfn.sh -c mychannel -l go up
```

it works well.

But, if I execute:

```
./byfn.sh -c mychannel -l node up
```

It would throw an exception because the container doesn't have the internet access to download the node module or else...

Comment: Dear Sharuru, could you post some code to illustrate how were you trying to solve a problem, what the problem you are facing and what is the expecting output. In this case it is much easier to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your best bet is to modify the chaincode [docker image used for building](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.2/sampleconfig/core.yaml#L529) to to have npm preconfigured with a proxy via:

> npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
>
> npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080

To modify it, you can just prefix "RUN" before the npm commands above in the [docker image template](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.2/images/ccenv/Dockerfile.in) that is used to create the docker file in which the chaincode is built:

> RUN npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
>
> RUN npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080

At node.js chaincode build time, the [following commands are run](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/78a3a8dadf2a82c2e535bcacaeb95fbdd4fbafde/core/chaincode/platforms/node/platform.go#L188):

```
cp -R /chaincode/input/src/. /chaincode/output && cd /chaincode/output && npm install --production
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I only searched in the fabric-sample repo to find out whether I can config the docker images used for build chaincode but forgot to search the fabric-bin folders XD.

Now, I can use my own pre-configured images for chaincode building. :)

Comment: Can someone provde me help doing this task?

Comment: where do you change the docker image? The dockerfile listed is from github so I'm not sure how you would change the one that the peer binary uses.