# Fabric chaincode container (nodejs) cannot access npm

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I appreciate help in this matter.

I have the latest images (2.2.0, CA 1.4.8), but I'm getting the error when I'm installing chaincode at the first peer:

```
failed to invoke chaincode lifecycle, error: timeout expired while executing transaction
```

I'm working behind a proxy, using a VPN.

I tried to increase the timeouts at the docker config, for all peers:

```
CORE_CHAINCODE_DEPLOYTIMEOUT=300s
CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT=300s
```

The process works perfectly up to that point (channel created, peers joined the channel). The chaincode can be installed manually with npm install.
I couldn't find an answer to this anywhere. Can someone provide guidance?

UPDATE: It seems that the chaincode container gets boostrap (and even attributed a random name), but gets stuck at:

```
+ INPUT_DIR=/chaincode/input
+ OUTPUT_DIR=/chaincode/output
+ cp -R /chaincode/input/src/. /chaincode/output
+ cd /chaincode/output
+ '[' -f package-lock.json -o -f npm-shrinkwrap.json ]
+ npm install --production
```

I believe it is the proxy blocking npm.

I tried to solve this with:

```
npm config set proxy proxy
npm config set https-proxy proxy
npm set maxsockets 3
```

After days of struggling, I've found a solution:
-Had to build a custom fabric nodeenv image, that contained the env variables to setup the npm proxy vars: as in [node chaincode instantiate behind proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52354240/node-chaincode-instantiate-behind-proxy). After that, I've setup the following env vars in docker.yaml:

```
  - CORE_CHAINCODE_NODE_RUNTIME=my_custom_image
  - CORE_CHAINCODE_PULL=true
```

Comment: Change these variables and see if you still get the same error.
`CORE_CHAINCODE_EXECUTETIMEOUT=60S`
`CORE_PEER_KEEPALIVE_CLIENT_TIMEOUT=60S`
`CORE_PEER_KEEPALIVE_DELIVERYCLIENT_TIMEOUT=60S`

Comment: Hey @KartikChauhan , thanks for the suggestion. Should I change those at docker-compose-test-net.yaml and docker-compose-e2e.yaml, for both peers?

Comment: Try changing them for a single peer first. It'd help us in narrowing down the issue. I'm assuming there's something wrong with your chaincode, not the network.

Comment: It can not be the chaincode, as I installed the same chaincode on another machine, and it works

Comment: Do you still get the same error after setting those variables?

Comment: Yes. I have added them to docker-compose-test-net.yaml, with values 300s, and still does not work. But when I run the chaincode with "node index" , there seems to be no error @KartikChauhan

Comment: Do you see any logs in the orderer container?

Comment: Yes, but mostly warnings: https://gist.github.com/RafaelAPB/4ff52c2f6cb561a481c20cf072d59641
@KartikChauhan

Comment: Furthermore, the machine is running behind a proxy

Comment: @Gari Singh  could you please assist me on this issue?

Comment: @Rafael, would you describe more explicitly what you did? Where did you create the new image definition and how did you get the peer binary to point to it? I'm having the same issue on fabric 2.3 and 2.2 with the "Write your first application" example when calling the following script which calls the peer binary:  $./network.sh deployCC -ccn basic -ccp ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-javascript/ -ccl javascript

Comment: Sorry for the late answer @Goku. To create the image you will need to build the docker file from https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-node; and give it your image name

Answer (score 0):

Useful! For Chinese users, npmjs may sometimes be disconnected and can build their own instances.

For example, if I use version 2.3.1, Download https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-node/tree/v.2.3.1 Edition. Then enter docker/fabric-nodeenv, modify the Dockerfile, and add a line to modify the warehouse source for npmjs:

```
RUN npm config set registry http://registry.npm.taobao.org
```

The entire file is as follows:

```
ARG NODE_VER=12.16.1
FROM node:${NODE_VER}-alpine
RUN npm config set registry http://registry.npm.taobao.org
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    make \
    python \
    g++;
RUN mkdir -p /chaincode/input \
    && mkdir -p /chaincode/output \
    && mkdir -p /usr/local/src;
ADD build.sh start.sh /chaincode/
```

Then build a docker image, using the command

```
docker image build-t whatever/fabric-nodeenv:2.3.
```

Wait a few minutes, and he'll build the image, and then with ***docker images***, you'll see the image he created

Finally, in peer's configuration file, add in peer-environment

```
 - CORE_CHAINCODE_NODE_RUNTIME=whatever/fabric-nodeenv:2.3
```

Hope it can help others！

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use an npm proxy registry like verdaccio, the rebuild nodeEnv image.

You can find a complete step-by-step guide on this article https://medium.com/@badrbellaj/how-to-deploy-node-js-chaincode-on-an-offline-machine-6677cb6d8f8d